# Replacing a group of words from a long document

Tags: python, regex

I was trying to solve this problem.
I have a long form technical document (600 pages). I need to substitute group of words with their abbreviations. Say, 'Long Form Document' is to be detected and replaced with LFD in the text.
I have a list of these group of words and their abbreviation. Also, the length of words is not fixed, it ranges from 2-6 words to be replaced by one single abbreviation.
I have tried creating n-grams and substituting but it distorts the document with unnecessary combinations and count of tokens is important. I also tried using a regex with window of 5 words and capital alphabets not preceded by full stop. Please suggest a suitable solution.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Below is an example in Python 3. There is no tokenisation: all possible terms to be abbreviated are simply or'ed together into a pattern, and the match is replaced with the corresponding abbreviation.

The performance of this solution with a large dictionary of abbreviations is to be determined experimentally.

If 600 pages are too much to be loaded into memory, a file can be loaded line by line, assuming that no group goes across several lines. If it can happen, a window of two or three lines can be processed at a time, then advancing by one line.

```py
import re

text = '''I was trying to solve this problem. I have a long form technical document (600 pages).
I need to substitute group of words with their abbreviations.
Say, 'Long Form Document' is to be detected and replaced with LFD in the text.
I have a list of these group of words and their abbreviation.
Also, the length of words is not fixed, it ranges from 2-6 words to be replaced by one single abbreviation.
I have tried creating n-grams and substituting but it distorts the document with unnecessary combinations and count of tokens is important.
I also tried using a regex with window of 5 words and capital alphabets not preceded by full stop. Please suggest a suitable solution.'''

abbr = {
    'Long Form Document': 'LFD',
    'Short Form Focument': 'SFD'
}

def abbreviate (text: str, abbr: dict) -> str:
    pattern = re.compile ('|'.join (abbr.keys ()), re.I)
    return re.sub (pattern, lambda m: abbr [m.group()], text)

# Test:
print (abbreviate (text, abbr))
```

Output:

```
I was trying to solve this problem. I have a long form technical document (600 pages).
I need to substitute group of words with their abbreviations.
Say, 'LFD' is to be detected and replaced with LFD in the text.
I have a list of these group of words and their abbreviation.
Also, the length of words is not fixed, it ranges from 2-6 words to be replaced by one single abbreviation.
I have tried creating n-grams and substituting but it distorts the document with unnecessary combinations and count of tokens is important.
I also tried using a regex with window of 5 words and capital alphabets not preceded by full stop. Please suggest a suitable solution.
```